# How to Loop through a column in VBA with Muiltiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to highlight expiry dates in Excel VBA. I need Column B to Highlight dates that will expire within the next month and Column c to highlight dates that will expire within 4 - 6 months. At present the code works if I delete columns and run the code on one column at a time e.g.

```
Name            Green Will Expire within 1 Month    
Name 1          01/01/2013    
Name 2          17/07/2013    
Name 3          03/04/2013    
Name 4          24/03/2013    
Name 5          16/07/2013    
Name 6          26/01/2013    
Name 7          28/06/2013    
Name 8          01/07/2013    
Name 9          09/01/2013    
Name 10         31/07/2013
```

Name (Column A), Green Will Expire within 1 Month (Column B).

If I run the code with these two columns only (Having deleted Column C) the code works fine. If I include my third column, Orange Expires in 4 - 6 Months (Column C):

```
   Name     Green Will Expire within 1 Month    Orange Expires in 4 - 6 Months
Name 1          01/01/2013                          01/01/2013
Name 2          17/07/2013                          01/12/2013
Name 3          03/04/2013                          03/04/2013
Name 4          24/03/2013                          20/11/2013
Name 5          16/07/2013                          16/07/2013
Name 6          26/01/2013                          26/01/2013
Name 7          28/06/2013                          28/06/2013
Name 8          01/07/2013                          01/07/2013
Name 9          09/01/2013                          09/01/2013
Name 10         31/07/2013                          31/07/2013
```

Only the second for loop works. I need both of these for loops to run without having to delete any columns.

VBA Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In Range("B2:B1000").Cells
        If Cell.Value <= Date + 30 And Not (Cell.Value < Date) And IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In Range("C2:C1000").Cells
         If Cell.Value <= Date + 180 And Not (Cell.Value <= Date + 120) And IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
         Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
         End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include a copy of the code you are currently using. We can't read your mind, and in order to troubleshoot your code, we kinda need to see it :)

Comment: Honest Mistake, I thought I had pasted it.

Comment: No worries. Part of your conditional statement will always evaluate to `False` based on the sample data you provide. See my answer below for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of your conditional statement will *always* evaluate to `False` if Column C is not empty:

`And IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)`

On a related note, the same fragment is in the second loop, so you may want to remove it from there, too. But I am not sure if that part would be required logic. In any case, the same holds: If column D is **not** empty, this will always evaluate to false, so the body of the `If...Then` will be omitted.

Comment: Removed the line And IsEmpty(Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) from both for loops and it works great. Thank so much I have been tearing my hair out :)

Comment: Excellent. If my answer has solved your problem, please consider marking it as "Accepted".  Cheers!